# Insert string in file with sed

Tags: shell, sed, ash

I have a file `tmp` with the following content.

```
<port>1554</port><tt>file</tt>
```

I want to insert a string with `sed` command. I use this command

```bash
sed -i '/<port>/a "HELLO"' tmp
```

but the string `"HELLO"` is not inserted after the `<port>` tag. What's wrong with the `sed` command?

the desired output is :

```
<port>1554</port>HELLO<tt>file</tt>
```

Comment: so what is the desired output?

Comment: How about `sed -i 's/(<port>)/\1HELLO/' tmp` ?

Comment: I use OpenWRT system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a replacement actually, but it does the job:

```
sed -i 's/<\/port>/<\/port>HELLO/g'
```

or

```
sed -i 's#</port>#</port>HELLO#g'
```

Comment: to prevent having to escape all the slashes, you can use another delimiter: `sed 's#</port>#blabla#g'`.

Comment: @fedorqui, thank you! I did not know this feature of sed. It is going to save me some time in the future, I am sure.